# Unable Auhorize Access to REST API end service with Azure Data Factory with Token Error status code 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have configured our Azure Data Factory with a REST Link Service. I have obtained a valid token from the end service.
The token successfully works when using the token with POSTMAN, but the token returns Error status code 401 Unauthorized with Azure Data Factory.

As you can see with POSTMAN when I send a GET request with the Token I get data back:

[image]

However, with Azure Data Factory I get the error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=RestCallFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Rest call failed with client error, status code 401 Unauthorized, please check your activity settings.\nRequest URL: https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com/apiCore/api/countries.\nResponse: ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

The ADF Link Service is a follows:

[image]

Can someone see something obvioius that would prevent access due 401 Unauthorized status with ADF?

I have also tried the following ADF configuration. However, I'm getting the same error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the Headers page of Postman show, does it have an entry with the Token?

Comment: Hi @ScottMildenberger, thanks for reaching out. Please see update in my question showing what the Headers page looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing the authHeader name to `Authorization` and the value to `Bearer <your API key>`. I suspect from the screenshot of Postman that is what it’s doing. If that does not work then please provide a link to the documentation. This explains [Bearer](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) tokens.

You might also check the lifetime of your access token and make sure it doesn’t expire after an hour, for example.

I did a quick test against a REST API I know (Power BI REST API). The linked service looks like this and the value for the Authorization header was `Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE`.

[image: REST API Linked Service]

The dataset looks like:

[image: REST API dataset]

The source of the Copy activity looks like:

[image: copy activity source]

This succeeded.

I would suggest you contact pm2.preqinsolutions.com support to see if they can provide more information on your access token / API key and have them confirm that the API isn't restricted to be accessed from only certain allowed API addresses. (ADF will not be accessing it from an on-premises IP address like your laptop.) You might also change the REST API linked service to use a self-hosted integration runtime instead of an Azure integration runtime to validate the IP address the API is called from isn't the issue.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't work. I'm still getting the error ```status code 401 Unauthorized```. The following is the link to documentation. https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com/apiCore/swagger/index.html.
Personally, I think the issue is that Authentication with ADF occurs with the 'HEADER' information, whereas the image authentication occurs with Authorization. But I could be wrong

Comment: The documentation confirms what I suggested. Maybe you need single quotes around your API Key? 
`GET apiCore/api/Countries
Authorization: Bearer 'APIKEYHERE'`
The Authorization header is a header.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks again for reaching out. However, I would disagree with you. In any case I have updated the question to demonstrate the configuration you have suggested, however, I'm still getting the same error. Can you provide a sample/screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Any additional thoughts on this question please?

Comment: @Patterson I added some further screenshots and text to my answer. I did confirm this works on a different API. I don't have access to your API to test against it.